# Metal assertion `A command encoder is already encoding to this command buffer`

Tags: objective-c, gpu, assert, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I am using Metal in my project and I have encapsulated some of the kernels as functions kind of the same way as `MetalPerformanceShaders` suggests.

So each my Metal kernel has Objective-C class with the method:

```
- (void)encodeToCommandBuffer:(id<MTLCommandBuffer>)cmdBuffer
                 inputTexture:(id<MTLTexture>)inputTexture
                outputTexture:(id<MTLTexture>)outputTexture
                    inputSize:(TextureSize)inputSize
                   outputSize:(TextureSize)outputSize
{
    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> enc = [cmdBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    
    [enc setComputePipelineState:_state];
    
    //set arguments to the state
    
    [enc dispatchThreadgroups:_threadgroupsPerGrid threadsPerThreadgroup:_threadsPerThreadgroup];
    [enc endEncoding];
}
```

The problem is that my code crashes with the assertion:

`failed assertion A command encoder is already encoding to this command buffer`

Issue is random, happens at different functions. The error description is self explanatory, but what I am curious is - crashes happen in my `encodeToCommandBuffer` methods. In the pipeline I also use Image Processing functions from `MetalPerformanceShaders` and these are also get called with `encodeToCommandBuffer` method and these do not crash.

So it is clear that my understanding how `encodeToCommandBuffer` method should be written is wrong. How do I need to modify the code? Do I need to check for cmdBuffer state somehow? That it is ready to produce new Encoder. And what if it's not? Do I need to have some sort of while loop that will wait until buffer is ready?

Comment: The reality is that you need to organize your code in a way that doesn't pass a command buffer with an unfinished encoder to the functions like `encodeToCommandBuffer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorted out. My pipeline is processing multiple instances in parallel, and I made a mistake in the code - pipeline tried to process all instances through the same command buffer, when it was not intended.